# Warning while reading tif file

Tags: r, spatial, gdal, r-raster, terra

I receive the following warning while reading Corine land cover data in tif format either using `raster` or `terra` package.

```
R <- raster::raster(CLC_Tiff)
```

> Warning message:
> In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
> GDAL Message 1: The definition of projected CRS EPSG:3035 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry, which may cause issues during reprojection operations. Set GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration option to EPSG to use official parameters (overriding the ones from GeoTIFF keys), or to GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.

Here is the projection

```
raster::projection(R)
[1] "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
```

Similarly for terra:

```
R <- terra::rast(CLC_Tiff, crs = "EPSG:3035")
Warning message:
In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) :
  GDAL Message 1: The definition of projected CRS EPSG:3035 got from GeoTIFF keys is not the same as the one from the EPSG registry, which may cause issues during reprojection operations. Set GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE configuration option to EPSG to use official parameters (overriding the ones from GeoTIFF keys), or to GEOKEYS to use custom values from GeoTIFF keys and drop the EPSG code.
```

```
terra::crs(R)
[1] "PROJCRS[\"ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        DATUM[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101004,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9820]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",10,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",4321000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",3210000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3035]]"
```

I can in principle use `suppressWarnings()` around the function to avoid this warning.
However, I'd like to 1) know the reason for this; 2) is there a way to avoid this; and 3) is it something I should care about for subsequent analyses using terra/raster/sf packages?

Comment: This question may be helpful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/450882/gtiff-srs-source-configuration

Comment: Yes, `suppressWarnings` will make the warning disappear.  But warnings are there for a reason.  Best take note of them.  especially when they suggest, as they do here, that the end result may be unreliable.  Did you try any of the fixes mentioned in the warning?  if so, what was the effect?  If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks... As I mentioned in the original question, I do not need to use `suppressWarnings`. I was able to switch this warning off by using the following command `terra::setGDALconfig("GTIFF_SRS_SOURCE", "EPSG")`. Please see also: https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr/issues/103. However, I want to know the reason behind that not onlyto hide it, and how this may affect the subsequent analyses.

Comment: I think you probably have misaligned versions of GDAL and something the depends on it. The CRS you posted contains the line `"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area"`. The [OGC WKT](https://epsg.io/3035) for EPSG 3035 has that for OGC WKT v.1 but OGC WKT v.2 records it as [`"Europe Equal Area 2001"`](https://epsg.io/19986). As far as I can tell they're [the same thing](https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/2021/notebooks/L2/02-projections.html) so I don't think it should matter but if you update all your geospatial packages I suspect the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the file has a CRS that contains an EPSG code and a bunch of parameters. These parameters do not match the parameters for the same EPSG code in the database that GDAL uses.

Here is a comparison showing that they are quite different in terms of the characters used.

```
terra::gdal()
#[1] "3.7.2"
terra::crs("EPSG:3035")
# [1] "PROJCRS[\"ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        ENSEMBLE[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble\",\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1989\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1990\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1991\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1992\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1993\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1994\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1996\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1997\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2000\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2005\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2014\"],\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[0.1]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Europe Equal Area 2001\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9820]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",10,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",4321000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",3210000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Statistical analysis.\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe - European Union (EU) countries and candidates. Europe - onshore and offshore: Albania; Andorra; Austria; Belgium; Bosnia and Herzegovina; Bulgaria; Croatia; Cyprus; Czechia; Denmark; Estonia; Faroe Islands; Finland; France; Germany; Gibraltar; Greece; Hungary; Iceland; Ireland; Italy; Kosovo; Latvia; Liechtenstein; Lithuania; Luxembourg; Malta; Monaco; Montenegro; Netherlands; North Macedonia; Norway including Svalbard and Jan Mayen; Poland; Portugal including Madeira and Azores; Romania; San Marino; Serbia; Slovakia; Slovenia; Spain including Canary Islands; Sweden; Switzerland; Türkiye (Turkey); United Kingdom (UK) including Channel Islands and Isle of Man; Vatican City State.\"],\n        BBOX[24.6,-35.58,84.73,44.83]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3035]]"

terra::crs(R)
#[1] "PROJCRS[\"ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        DATUM[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101004,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9820]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",10,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",4321000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",3210000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3035]]"
```

But in itself, that does not mean that the CRS is meaningfully different.

I do not see any difference if I do:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
x <- project(v, "EPSG:3035")
y <- project(v, crs(R))
plot(x)
lines(y, col="red")
```